# logout by deleting cookies

Tags: python, django, cookies

I used this code to logout from a django web app. but if I add url manually, it easily redirect me to that page,but that shouldn't happen since I'm logged out.

```
def logout_view(request):
    user = check_validation(request)
    response = HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')  #redirect to login page
    stoken = SessionToken(user=user)  #stoken is object for SessionToken
    response.delete_cookie(stoken.session_token)
    return response`
```

Please tell me any solution to this problem,or anything that i am missing in this code.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

In Django, there is a built in logout function. Use it, instead of baking your own:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

def logout_page(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks !! It helped me but actually after logging out when i add url manually(for eg. http://login/home/post) then it actually redirects me to post page.but i want that there should be a functionality that redirects me to login page even if i am trying to access another page from that site.